# Featured images duplicating and replacing next image

Tags: php, images, featured-post

Took over a project, and one of the errors is the featured images (and certain others rendered in a similar way) are duplicating themselves and replacing the next image thumbnail.

```php
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="snack__thumb snack__thumb--featured" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'medium' ); ?>');">
<?php
  if (has_category('whitepaper')) { ?>
    <div class="snack__banner"><span>whitepaper</span></div>
  <?php 
  } 
?>
```

I've read that not ending a loop with something like wp_reset_postdata(); can cause this type of error however I haven't been able to get it solved.

Relevant plugins installed are
`NS Featured Posts`
`Ajax-Load-More` (Error happening within Load-more field)

This happens on the home page as well in this loop

```php
<?php while ($latest_posts->have_posts()) : ?>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    ?php 
      $latest_posts->the_post();
      include(locate_template('loop-templates/content-snack.php'));
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php 
    if ($latest_posts->max_num_pages > 1) {
      echo(do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more id="posts-loader" container_type="div" post_type="post" posts_per_page="6" post_format="standard" pause="true" post__not_in="'.implode(",",$special_ids).'" scroll="false" transition_container_classes="row" button_label="See more posts"]'));
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Hey Ranson Namba, can you include a more complete snippet of code. Your current code doesn't really tell us anything. If the issue is with your main loop show us that. If it's a custom loop, show that. And can you give more context around your issue? Is this a single post? An archive? Is javascript or the load more plugin causing this? Have you tried deactivating that plugin? Or turning javascript off?

Comment: Updated with more code. I don't believe that a custom loop has been created. This is  mainly in a plugin ajax-load-more, the developer said that it can be an error in the repeater template, or queries higher up not being reset with wp_reset_query()

Answer (score 0):

This was due to having an inline `<?php $post = get_post()?>`
After moving this out and making it global, images stopped duplicating.